# What's is the meaning of held a phone call

Tags: sentence-meaning

Is phrase "held a phone call" means received a phone call or made a phone call?

Comment: That is not a very common phrase but it would just mean that a phone call took place - it doesn't tell you who called who.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. can we know from the sentence that who is initiate the call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hold a phone call usually means to organise a phone call in advance. (or usually a phone conference, maybe with speakerphones on either end, possibly even arranged by underlings). It's usually a slightly more formal occurrence than the phoning of somebody initiated by one side - you might agree to ring your kids teacher about their behaviour at lunchtime for instance.

If you google "hold a phone call" you will see lots of examples of world leaders agreeing to "hold a phone call" to discuss political issues.

It doesn't really matter who actually dials the other first in this instance.

So the past tense *held a phone call* just refers to a phone call that happened in the past

> The US and Iranian Leaders *held a phone call* to discuss rising tensions in the area

Comment: Thanks you very much. that really help.

Answer (score 0):

In my mind, associating "hold" and "phone call" means that a phone call is temporarily suspended, until one of the speakers does something else.

> to put on hold = waiting to be connected while making a telephone call (Google definition)

---

- to have a phone call = to talk on the phone; not known who made the call;
- to make a phone call = to dial a number and talk when the other person answers;
- to receive a phone call = to answer the phone when it is ringing.